# git bash shell find on windows: need to find a directory that contains file and run command

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have 2 problems that really boil down to one solution

I am high up in my file system.  I need "find" to search for directories that contain a file "*.tf" or a directory ".git",  run a command, then move and not search sub directories.

I have to use windows git bash shell and find.   I think -execdir from find is the correct option to run

find in git bash shell it returning

```
find . -type d -name .git -execdir git pull \;
find: The relative path 'C' is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH"
```

I have tried

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd {}; git pull;" \;
```

but that still finds all subdirectories.   it does not move on to the next sibling directory

Comment: found the answer
    find . -type d -name .git -exec dirname {} \; | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd "$0"; && ....'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec dirname {} \; | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd "$0"; && ....'
```

I now hate safari autocorrection.  keep changing dirname to surname